# An apparent paradox in General relativity using a binary black hole

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, spacetime, event-horizon, binary-stars

**Note**: Quantum gravity effects are ignored in this question.

Imagine 2 black holes each with mass $m$ approaching each other and after some time the Event Horizons (EHs) of both black holes touch each other. But the singularities of both black holes are outside the event horizon of the other black hole. Now since **classically** EH itself is not made up of matter it can come out of another EH (in quantum gravity this may not be possible since the surface of EH has many properties and it also stores information on the surface [when observed from outside](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_hole_complementarity) and information cannot leave another EH) and we can do something and separate the black holes and their EHs. I think this is possible in principle. I am neglecting Gravitational waves radiated by this binary. **Can something happen and make this separation impossible even in principle?**

One way I think we can separate these black holes is if those 2 are Reissner–Nordström black holes with same charge q  (they don't repel because their mass dominates over charge) then in principle we can get some very highly charged but with opposite sign objects (not necessarily black holes and they can be moved easily) with mass $M$ and charge $Q$ ( $|Q|>>|q|$ and $|M|>>|m|$) and put one to the left of left black hole and the other to the right of the right black hole. These large objects will be almost at rest and the 2 black holes will be attracted to these large objects and their EHs will be separated from contact.

Now in another similar situation a test particle is exactly in the middle of 2 black holes. After sometime the black holes attract and their EHs meet and the particle is in both EHs and since this test particle is at the center it will be always at rest even inside the EHs (since if it moves towards either singularity it has to move away from another singularity which is not possible since the radial coordinate behaves like a time like coordinate and moving radially away is impossible inside an EH).

[image: Test particle is in blue. Singularities are in black.]

Test particle is in blue. Singularities are in black.

Now we can do something like earlier and separate the EHs. Now from the symmetry at the end the test particle should still be at the center, so it has to come out of both EHs. **But in classical GR no particle can come out of an EH.** What is wrong in this description and how to resolve this paradox?

Comment: There are _no_ mathematical expressions for a spacetime with two black holes.  Your premise is flawed.

Comment: The LIGO observation of the merging of two black holes shows what happens when event horizons are near and are shared. https://www.ligo.caltech.edu/video/ligo20160211v3

Comment: @annav thanks. But the video is very fast after the two event horizons touch. Even at 0.25x it is still fast.

Comment: It is because of the great gravitational attraction between the two massive black holes. The LIGO site has a lot of analysis of the data, if you search it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is impossible to use Reissner-Nordström black holes in you scenario, because these black holes assume spherical symmetry of spacetime. This is a good approximation if other sources are far away and produce only small distortions around the black hole (BH) you analyze, but in your case the symmetry is highly broken. Just the fact that the two event horizons meet means the distortions from BH1 around BH2 is not negligible.

The event horizon is also not a property of singularity but of spacetime itself. You cannot imagine two spheres around singularities and if the singularity 1 is not inside a sphere of singularity 2 it can go away. The event horizons will merge in nontrivial way and create one event horizon, and everything underneath it will not be able to get away. The nonlinearity of Einstein field equations also means that you cannot imagine binary BH as simple combination of two isolated BHs.

Another thing is, that it is know that the scenario in your picture is unstable and it radiates gravitational waves  until one symmetrical black hole is created. From what I know, the process is very quick, but someone else more knowledgeable in this area will be better suited to explain this.

Comment: Ok I did a big blunder assuming EHs will not merge.